# Editing LuaLaTeX files in emacs

Tags: luatex, emacs, editors

(A follow-up question to [Which is the best editor for LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18904/which-is-the-best-editor-for-luatex))

Emacs offers the LaTeX-mode in AUCTeX for editing LaTeX files, while it has the Lua-mode for editing Lua-files.

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
for i=1,2,3 do
for j=1,2,3 do
tex.sprint("Test");
end
end
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

In Emacs latex-mode I get the following screenshot:

[image]

But it is not possible to indent the lua-code with the tab-key or highlight Lua-code key words. If I turn on lua-mode in emacs, I get editing features for the Lua-code, but not for the latex-code, e.g.:

[image]

Is it possible to have both modes work together? (I have looked at this page: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes but I am not sure which mode to use and how to set it up)

Comment: It surely is possible. E.g. the orgtbl-mode works inside *.tex documents. But probably someone has to write such a mode for the display of Lua inside a tex document.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It may be *possible* to have Emacs switch major modes depending on the position of point, but this can quickly become computationally-intensive and can break workflows (especially those that make heavy use of temporary variables). It would be better to adopt the Org model of source code editing: send the interesting bits to a separate buffer and change the mode on *that* buffer. (For the record, I tried using indirect buffers, but having different font-locks on two views of the same buffer seems to trip up Emacs a bit.)

Bind `LaTeX-edit-Lua-code-start` to your favorite key.  Beware though; editing is asynchronous.  You must save for it to reinsert itself into the parent.  Kill the buffer, lose your changes.

#### Update:

I've uploaded the code to [GitHub](https://github.com/vermiculus/auctex-lua)
  and submitted a pull request to MELPA under the name `auctex-lua`,
  and it is available to download through that package repository.
If you have not done so already,
  you will have to ['install' MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#installing) by
  adding it to your `.emacs` anywhere before a call to `package-initialize`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'package-archives
  '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
```

I can confirm that the install works swimmingly!
For the code, please refer to [GitHub](https://raw.github.com/vermiculus/auctex-lua/master/auctex-lua.el).
It would be impossible to maintain on here. `:-)`

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Good news, and thank you for your notification.

Comment: @KeksDose Can't lie about what I do and don't know :) I might be learning some Lua pretty soon though---I'd like to see how far it can take me to work on the rivers problem (if at all).